# Do 'front groups' exist in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom

The Oxford Dictionary of Environment and Conservation [defines *front group* as](https://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780199641666.001.0001/acref-9780199641666-e-9466?rskey=NHKY5i&result=3489):

> *A front group is a pressure group that is structured to look like a voluntary association, but may in reality be controlled by a particular interest (such as a company, industry, or political party), and which may give the appearance of being set up to do one thing but actually be set up to do something else on behalf of its parent group*

Examples of such groups in the US are listed, but do such groups exist in the UK?

Comment: The answer is almost surely yes, but I don't have any ready examples for you.

Comment: A lot of this is going to vary based on opinion as well. My personal example would be evangelist courses such as Alpha, but many people would disagree.

Comment: It does seem very difficult to find a solid example.

Comment: Perhaps they don't give such examples because it's easier to win libel suit in the UK... https://www.npr.org/sections/parallels/2015/03/21/394273902/on-libel-and-the-law-u-s-and-u-k-go-separate-ways

Answer (score 2):

There are, perhaps, two types of "front" group. Those in which the "fronting" nature is an open secret, and those in which it is a true secret.

Among the "open secret" are Sinn Fein,  A front for the IRA.  There is "[Effective Education centre](https://www.effectiveeducation.net/)", known locally as a front for Dianetics and Scientology.  There is the Alpha movement, an front for the Church of England.

These are open secrets, and many might dispute one or another as being a "front" since (for example) the links between Sinn Fein and the IRA are so well known that there is no real deception involved. Since the end of the Troubles, one could argue that the IRA has ceased to exist as an active paramilitary body. The Sinn Fein "front" has replaced the IRA "body".

Then there are the truly secret front groups.  And, of course, nobody knows about these. All the American front groups are either historic, or open secrets.